# A function to create interaction variables: what is wrong with the code?

Tags: python, function, pandas

I’ve written a function below that takes, as arguments, a dataframe (`df`) and two of its column names (`var1`, `var2`).  Then it creates interaction variables for the two variables and adds those columns to the original dataframe.  The code works when I hard code it, but when I try to call the function like:

```
create_interactions(my_dataframe, 'variable1', 'variable2')
my_dataframe
```

I receive no errors but the new columns are not added to the dataframe - it returns the original dataframe.  What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

```
def create_interactions(df,var1,var2):
    variables = df[[var1,var2]] 
    for i in range(0, variables.columns.size):
        for j in range(0, variables.columns.size):
            col1 = str(variables.columns[i])
            col2 = str(variables.columns[j])
            if i <= j:
                name = col1 + "*" + col2
                df = pd.concat([df, pd.Series(variables[col1] * variables[col2], name=name)], axis=1)
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you are returning anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing `df = ...` doesn't modify the original df.  It just makes a new local variable with your new df.

You could return `df` from your function, and then use it like `df = create_interactions(df, 'var1', 'var2')`.

But if you do want your function to modify the original `df`, it might be better to change your last line to this:

```
df[name] = pd.Series(variables[col1] * variables[col2], name=name)
```

This will insert the new column into the existing DataFrame.

There are a couple other odd things about your code.  You create a new variable called `variables` that just contains two columns of the original `df`.  Then you loop over `range(0, variables.columns.size)`.  But since you defined `variables` to have only two columns, `variables.columns.size` will always be two.  Later, you grab columns from `variables`, but these same columns are already present in `df`, so you could just grab them from `df` instead.

Also, your code creates "interactions" of each variable with itself, which seems a bit odd.  I think your code could be simplified to this:

```
def create_interaction(df,var1,var2):
    name = var1 + "*" + var2
    df[name] = pd.Series(df[var1] * df[var2], name=name)
```

Since you only accept exactly two variables, there will be exactly one interaction, so you don't need any loops at all.  (And I renamed it `create_interaction` to indicate this! :-)  Just grab the two specified variables and multiply them.

Comment: Yes, you're correct :).  I, in fact, want to generalize the code so that I can have as many variables as I like and create interactions for all of them. So I suppose I should write: `create_interaction(df,*args)` ?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JamesEaves: Yeah, you could do that, or just `create_interaction(df, vars)`, where `vars` is a list of columns.  In that case, it will likely be more readable to use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) rather than nested loops.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in this line:

```
df = pd.concat([df, pd.Series(variables[col1] * variables[col2], name=name)], axis=1)
```

you are creating a new dataframe and assigning it to the variable `df`.  `df` is no longer pointing to the `df` that was passed.  What's more is that you don't return it, you assume it edited the original `df`.  To get it to behave the way you want, do this:

```
def create_interactions(df,var1,var2):
    variables = df[[var1,var2]] 
    for i in range(0, variables.columns.size):
        for j in range(0, variables.columns.size):
            col1 = str(variables.columns[i])
            col2 = str(variables.columns[j])
            if i <= j:
                name = col1 + "*" + col2
                df.loc[:, name] = variables[col1] * variables[col2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check scoping on your variables. Within the create_interactions function, you never change dataframe directly. First, you copy the dataframe in:

```
variables = df[[var1,var2]]
```

then you assign the dataframe variable in:

```
 df = pd.concat([df, pd.Series(variables[col1] * variables[col2], name=name)], axis=1)
```

This creates a new df, which you could return. Alternatively, you could change the df directly, ie. df['foo'] = 'bar'.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that creates a new dataframe with the original columns plus unique pairs of columns and their corresponding products:

```
def create_interactions(df):
    df_int = df.copy()
    for i in range(0, len(df.columns)-1):
        for j in range(i+1, len(df.columns)):
            name = str(df.columns[i]) + ' * ' + str(df.columns[j])
            df_int.loc[:, name] = df[str(df.columns[i])] * df[str(df.columns[j])]
    return df_int
```